# An if statement within a switch statement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm having difficulties seeing why one way works and way doesn't.

I have;

```
switch (key)
        {
            //If Game over Label is visible, enable the m and e buttons
            if(mGameOverLabel->GetVisible())
            {
                case 'm': case 'M':
                    ResetScreen();
                    break;

                case 'e': case 'E':
                //  //Exit the game
                    Stop();
                    break;
            } else {

                case ' ':
                    mSpaceship->Shoot();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

For the case of the m and e, even though mGameOverLabel is set to false at this current time, I can still press M and E and these will react according to the methods, but If I change it to this for M it will then only work when I need it too. Am I missing something here?!

```
switch (key)
        {
            //If Game over Label is visible, enable the m and e buttons

            case 'm': case 'M':
                if(mGameOverLabel->GetVisible()) ResetScreen();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Can you do you before swicth statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `switch` basically does a `goto` to the appropriate case label. Any logic above the `case` will not be executed.

Comment: ah, that would explain all! Thanks!